# Unable to Start Activity... android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.app: drawable/abc_vector_test with resource ID #0x7f07005c

Tags: java, android, facebook, drawable, android-vectordrawable

I´m trying to do an App that works with Firebase and authenticates with Google, Email and Facebook.

Is exactly in the phase of Facebook sync that I had this problem:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube, PID: 8112
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube/com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube:drawable/abc_vector_test with resource ID #0x7f07005c
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube:drawable/abc_vector_test with resource ID #0x7f07005c
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005c
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:891)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:673)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:993)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:983)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:922)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:693)
        at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:454)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.checkVectorDrawableSetup(ResourceManagerInternal.java:504)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:137)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:411)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:86)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.attachToWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:647)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureWindow(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:623)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:350)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:105)
        at com.example.aplicacintrabajandoenlanube.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from xml type drawable resource ID #0x7f07005c
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1264)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:952)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:877)
            ... 32 more
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenXmlAsset(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openXmlBlockAsset(AssetManager.java:1092)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadXmlResourceParser(ResourcesImpl.java:1248)
            ... 34 more
```

Just so U know, my Gradle has a folder that says 6.5, which I think is the versión of Gradle.

PS: I´m literally a starter, so I do not understand most of the things I´m doing and probably will do, so please, help me in the easiest way possible (hahahah)

Answer (score -1):

Analyzing the Stack Trace clearly I can depict that, It's causing an Runtime Exception since there is exactly no Resource found named `drawable/abc_vector_test` in your drawable folder.

Since Android didn't found the resource it's raising an `Resource Not Found Exception`. Kindly create the drawable file and then try running the app once.

For more information read the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.NotFoundException)

Comment: I've just ran into the exact same thing, and your answer is not helpful as it doesn't involve the root cause of the problem. The thing is that drawable/abc_vector_test is a native resource, and as far as I can tell, it is used by androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.java in method getDrawable(). From the looks of it, it is used to test if a known vector resource can be decoded properly before fetching the actual drawable you requested. Among other things, this will get called by AppCompatDelegateImpl attachToWindow(), which is why many see this on app launch.